# boolean isElementVisible = driver.findElement(By.id(“myHeaderDiv”)).isDisplayed(); is giving NoSuchElement Exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-java

Hi I am writing a script wherein I need to check if the element is present or not? However, when the element is not present then the following code is giving me   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
Is not the method suppose to return false if the element is not visible or no such element exists?

```
    boolean isElementVisible = driver.findElement(By.id(“myHeaderDiv”)).isDisplayed();
if (isElementVisible) {
    return true;
}else{
    System.out.println("Is visible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium for Java, if an element cannot be found, `driver.findElement(...)` will throw a `NoSuchElementException`. What you're seeing is the [documented and intended](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.1/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) behavior. Because the exception is thrown, your code does not continue, and `.isDisplayed()` is never evaluated. If you want to handle this case, you can use `driver.findElements(...)` and check the resulting size

```java
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("..."))
if (!elements.isEmpty() && elements.get(0).isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("element visible")
} else {
    System.out.println("element not visible")
}
```